# Foundation 5 is not working with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5 that working fine with all browser except IE8. I have also try with polyfill but still css issues exist on IE8.
Any other solution for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some businesses it is not a viable option to drop support for IE8. I had to get a Foundation 5 site working in IE8 and here are the steps I took to get it working.

**Breakdown:**

1. Use jQuery v1.x and not v2.x
2. Include IE8 grid support CSS
3. Include shims in HEAD after your CSS

   - cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2/html5shiv.js
   - s3.amazonaws.com/nwapi/nwmatcher/nwmatcher-1.2.5-min.js
   - html5base.googlecode.com/svn-history/r38/trunk/js/selectivizr-1.0.3b.js
   - cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.1.0/respond.min.js
   - github.com/es-shims/es5-shim - shim.js
4. Include Foundation js fix before initiating foundation
5. Include REM shim at very bottom of page

For a more in depth look at how to do this check out the link below:

https://kyco.io/blog/getting-foundation-5-to-work-in-ie8

Comment: It is better to post here the essential part of the solution and use link as reference.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/faq.html and http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compatibility.html:

> 1. Why doesn't Foundation support IE7 or IE8? Or: why we don't support a dying species.
>
> This is probably the biggest question we get. Consider this: most of
>   today's popular browsers automatically upgrade themselves including
>   Chrome, Firefox and Explorer (starting with 9). IE 8 is the last IE
>   supported on Windows XP, which Microsoft will officially stop
>   supporting next year. That played a part in our decision.
>
> Besides that, since Foundation 4, our framework is built mobile-first,
>   meaning it relies on media queries to layer in more complex layouts
>   and components. Browsers or devices that don't support media queries
>   will be restricted to a simple, single-column layout. In some ways,
>   Foundation 4 better supports IE6-7 insomuch as it provides a mobile
>   but not entirely broken experience. **If IE8 support is important for
>   your users / customers, you can use Foundation 3.2, which supports
>   IE8. It's not mobile first but it's good stuff.**

Comment: I have try with Foundation 3.2 but still that issues exist on IE8.