# Foundation 5 modal appears below .flex-video Youtube video in Internet Explorer

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am calling a Foundation 5 modal and everything works great except for IE (all versions).

I have a .flex-video Youtube video in the page and the modal content shows up behind the video.

I've tried setting the z-index on .flex-video to 0, but that doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foundation 5 is not working with IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164029/foundation-5-is-not-working-with-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

Foundation 5 does not suppoort IE8. Via FAQ

> our framework is built mobile-first, meaning it relies on media
>   queries to layer in more complex layouts and components. Browsers or
>   devices that don't support media queries will be restricted to a
>   simple, single-column layout.

http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/faq.html#question-1

If IE8 support is important for you can use foundation 3.2

Comment: I know this about Foundation, I checked the docs first before posting. The problem is with ALL VERSIONS OF IE, but I recieved an answer [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/15336-foundation-5-modal-appears-below-flex-video-youtube-video-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was given to me [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/15336-foundation-5-modal-appears-below-flex-video-youtube-video-in-internet-explorer).